# Dynamic script tag security

Tags: javascript, json, security, xmlhttprequest, jsonp

I am analyzing whether using dynamic script tags to do requests to some third party servers
is a good idea. Stackoverflow and a few other site had a couple of topics about these and I'm still left unsure that it's a good idea.

App is on server B.
Third party API is on server A.

If server B application is pulling server A's javascript API library, which in turn uses dynamic  tags to make calls to server A, I am guessing that the API library and the
returning code from the API itself is still within server B's domain sandbox ?

There are a couple of things I'm thinking of as well:

I am also evaluating whether it's more advisable to actually pull the library code to server B, vet it for security, host the JS source ourselves so that we don't blindly accept it just in case it changes over time.

In addition to that, I would make changes to server A's API library to make calls via our
proxy, which would whitelist domains along with logging every request long with a couple of other things, like making sure that only json and valid json is returned back to the client ...

Obviously I would like to avoid having to deal with this hot potato issue, but the decision to use this API has so far overriden my substantiated or not security worries.

Is there literature that holds weight that supports either side?

Answer (score 0):

The domain that is hosting the JavaScript (or json)  has no influence on the [Same-Origin Policy](http://code.google.com/p/browsersec/wiki/Part2).  It is entirely dependent on the domain that loads the script via a `<script>` tag.    That being said it maybe possible to load JSON from another domain with out their consent,  by using "[json callback hackery](http://jeremiahgrossman.blogspot.com/2007/01/gmail-xsrf-json-call-back-hackery.html)" .

I am not aware of any attack pattern involved in a client loading malicious JSON.   I can't think of a scenario when this would provide any impact what so ever.  It is a good idea to limit the scope of your proxy with a white list.